# Is it necessary to use placeholders when doing a query search on SQL?

Tags: python, sql, cs50

So I was doing the CS50 online course and for an assignment on SQL, I have to fill a database with names, house, and birth year. I've written a code as such..

```
first = full_name[0]
middle = full_name[1]
last = full_name[2]
db.execute("INSERT INTO students (first, middle, last) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
first, middle, last)
```

Is it okay to change that last line to

```
db.execute("INSERT INTO students (first, middle, last) VALUES (first, middle, last)")
```

Comment: Try it, and see what happens.

Comment: It gives me an error saying that there is no column ||first|| etc.. From what I've learned, using placeholders is the safest and best way, but I was just wondering why we couldn't just insert variables to the VALUES().

Comment: You'd need string concatenation; like `VALUES (' + first + ', ' + middle + ', ' + last + ')'`. Which, besides it doesn't read nice, is dangerous. Stick with parameters.

Comment: In that example I've already forgotten the quotes around strings, just another reason to use parameters